# Why printf alloc 4KB memory on heap?

Tags: c, linux, memory

See this demo:

```cpp
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Pause() {
    int v; {
        scanf("%d", &v);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Pause();
    printf("Hello.\n");
    malloc_trim(0);
    Pause();
    return 0;
}
```

mem status at the first `pause()`:

```
root     1288815  0.0  0.0  15616   844 pts/1    S+   21:13   0:00 ./a.out
```

mem status at the second `pause()`:

```
root     1288815  0.0  0.0  15620   844 pts/1    S+   21:13   0:00 ./a.out
```

I used `malloc_trim(0)` to make sure the released memory has been returned to OS, then I used pmap and found that the program allocated a page of memory on heap and won't be released. What is it?
I'm using centos.

Comment: Internal `stdout` buffers?

Comment: Perhaps the buffer is due to `scanf("%d", &v);`?

Comment: ASIDE: `#include <cstdio>` and `#include <cstdlib>` should be `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` since this question is tagged as [tag:c].

Comment: You use C++ compiler to compile the C code. Not good.

Comment: Thanks above. I added another Pause(), buffer seems to be due to printf instead of scanf.

Comment: The output buffer must be retained between calls to `printf`, because it is discharged either a) when full, b) when `'\n'` is output, c) with `fflush(stdout)`.